# Two webcams of the same model are not working

Tags: webcam, programming, c++, opencv

I've been developing a dual webcam system for stereoscopic purposes, in a linux enviroment, using c++ with the opencv library

The ideal setup would be with 2 webcams of the same model, but it didn't work,

So, i've changed one of them for another model, and it worked...

Here is the function i been using for view the two webcam:

```
void open_2cams()

{

VideoCapture cap(0); //open camera1
VideoCapture cap2(1); //open_camera2

Mat frame,frame2;

namedWindow("cam1",1);
namedWindow("cam2",1);


int i=0;
    for(;;)
    {
        cap >> frame;
        cap2 >> frame2;
        imshow("cam1", frame2);
        imshow("cam2", frame);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
    cap.release();cap2.release();
    destroyAllWindows();
}
```

and i take a look in the lsusb coomand at the terminal,

```
ID 1871:0101 Aveo Technology Corp. UVC camera
```

And the two webcam (of the original setup) have the same id!

There's a way to change the ID of any camera?

Comment: Please post the output of `ls /dev/video*`

Comment: There's no such folder..

Comment: What folder? This command will list all video devices. Note that there isn't a spece between the slash and the asterisk. You'll have at least one video device.